# Is this set a Lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

> Indicate if
>
> [image: Set]
>
> is a lattice. Justify.

---

**Definition** Let $(A,\preceq)$ be a ordered set. $(A,\preceq)$ is a *lattice* if between all pair of elements the supreme and the infimum must exist.

I think it is not a lattice since the atoms i.e. the $\color{red}{\text{red points}}$ do not have supreme because they have two maximum elements (in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$):

[image: Explanation]

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @mr_e_man thank you!! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Notice that there is a more obvious reason for it not to be a lattice: you have two minimal elements (the black one at the right of the blue ones is minimal), and in a lattice there is at most one. It is also questionable whether or not you can call atoms to elements in a poset with more than one minimal element. Perhaps you can, if it covers any minimal element which is below it...

Comment: Also, the red points don't have two maximum elements. They have two minimal upper bounds (the blue points). There's only one maximum element on this poset (and there is at most one in any poset; maximal elements could be more, but not in this case).